# How to export the output of Python code into a csv file

Tags: python

```
user_api = os.environ['Api_key']
location = input("Vpišite ime mesta: ")

def Vremenska_napoved():
    """Za kraj, ki ga uporabnik vnese mu funkcija izpiše stanje vremena za tisti trenutek"""

complete_api_link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location+"&appid="+user_api
api_link = requests.get(complete_api_link)
api_data = api_link.json()

if api_data ['cod'] == '404':
    print("Mesto ne obstaja: {}, Preverite pravilni vnos mesta za katerega želite vremensko napoved".format(location))
else:
    #naredimo spremenljivke za shranjevanje in prikaz podatkov o vremenu
    Temperatura = ((api_data['main']['temp']) - 273.15)
    Vlažnost = api_data['main']['humidity']
    Hitrost_vetra = api_data['wind']['speed']
    Občuti_se_kot = api_data['weather'][0]['description']
    Datum_čas = datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y | %I:%M:%S %p")




    print ("_____________________________________________________________")
    print ("Vremenska napoved za - {} || {}".format(location.upper(), Datum_čas))
    print ("_____________________________________________________________")

    print ("Trenutna temperatura: {:.2f} stopinj C".format(Temperatura))
    print ("Trenutna vlažnost:",Vlažnost, '%')
    print ("Trenutna hitrost vetra:",Hitrost_vetra ,'km/h')
    print ("Občuti se kot:",Občuti_se_kot)

Vremenska_napoved()
```

Weather in PODBREZJE || 03 May 2021 | 07:13:32 PM

---

Temp: 12.54 stopinj C
Hum: 54 %
W_speed: 3.09 km/h

So this is my code and the output given by python and I am wondering how I could save Temp, Hum and W_speed into the CSV file, because I want to collect weather data for 1 day and process it.

Comment: Hi! You could use pandas to store the values in a dataframe and store the output in a csv file!

Comment: I have already tried (saving in excel) but I do not know exactly how to use Temp, Hum, W_speed in the code.                                                                                                
import pandas as pd                                                                                               
podatki = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':[],'Hum':[],'W_speed':[]})                       
podatki_v_excel = pd.ExcelWriter("FromPython.xlsx",engine = 'xlsxwriter')   podatki.to_excel(podatki_v_excel,sheet_name = 'Zvezek1')                         podatki_v_excel.save()

Comment: Could you provide the json result of the api request?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but the `Vremenska_napoved()` function does absolutely nothing

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the answer!

The data is stored in a dictionary and a csv is created appending the new data.
If the file does not exists, the headers are added to the file.

I haven't tried the solution but the 'pseudocode' could help you with your requirements!

```
import os
import csv

user_api = os.environ['Api_key']
location = input("Vpišite ime mesta: ")

def Vremenska_napoved():
    """Za kraj, ki ga uporabnik vnese mu funkcija izpiše stanje vremena za tisti trenutek"""

    complete_api_link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+location+"&appid="+user_api
    api_link = requests.get(complete_api_link)
    api_data = api_link.json()

    if api_data ['cod'] == '404':
        print("Mesto ne obstaja: {}, Preverite pravilni vnos mesta za katerega želite vremensko napoved".format(location))
    else:
        #naredimo spremenljivke za shranjevanje in prikaz podatkov o vremenu
        Temperatura = ((api_data['main']['temp']) - 273.15)
        Vlažnost = api_data['main']['humidity']
        Hitrost_vetra = api_data['wind']['speed']
        Občuti_se_kot = api_data['weather'][0]['description']
        Datum_čas = datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y | %I:%M:%S %p")


        headers = ['Date', 'Temp', 'Hum', 'W_speed']
        filename = 'output.csv'
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)

        row = {
            'Date': Datum_čas
            'Temp': Temperatura,
            'Hum': Vlažnost,
            'W_speed': Hitrost_vetra
        }
        
        a_file = open(filename, "a")
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(a_file, headers)

        if not file_exists:
            dict_writer.writeheader()  # file doesn't exist yet, write a header

        dict_writer.writerow(row)
        a_file.close())

        print ("_____________________________________________________________")
        print ("Vremenska napoved za - {} || {}".format(location.upper(), Datum_čas))
        print ("_____________________________________________________________")

        print ("Trenutna temperatura: {:.2f} stopinj C".format(Temperatura))
        print ("Trenutna vlažnost:",Vlažnost, '%')
        print ("Trenutna hitrost vetra:",Hitrost_vetra ,'km/h')
        print ("Občuti se kot:",Občuti_se_kot)

Vremenska_napoved()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code and it works as needed